# Including `munit` tests that are excluded by default

Tags: scala, sbt, scalameta, scala-munit

I have an `munit` test:

```
package myawesomeproject

import munit.FunSuite

class MySillyTest extends FunSuite {
  val theTag = new munit.Tag("tagname")
  test("THETEST".tag(theTag)) {
    assertEquals(2, 3)
  }
}
```

and in my `build.sbt`, I want to exclude this test by default:

```
lazy val myawesomeproject = project
  .in(file("myawesomeproject"))
  .settings(
    // ...
    Test / testOptions += Tests.Argument(MUnitFramework, "--exclude-tags=tagname")
  )
```

When I run `test`, the test is excluded, as expected.

But when I try to manually override the exclusion with

```
myawesomeproject / testOnly -- --tests=THETEST --include-tags=tagname
```

then the test is *still not executed*, i.e. it seems that the command line setting does not override the `build.sbt` setting.

Are there any workarounds? How can I run a test that is excluded by default?

---

- Related issue: https://github.com/scalameta/munit/issues/562
- Official docs: https://scalameta.org/munit/docs/filtering.html

Comment: Removing unrelated munit tag which is used for MuleSoft MUnit testing framework. scalameta seems a more appropriate tag. Feel free to update the tags.

Comment: @aled Oh... Thanks. The pigeonhole principle states that if one keeps naming unit-test frameworks like `<latin-letter>unit`, then one will definitely run into a collision after the 27th framework.